# AngularJS + Parse REST API - Paging through more than 1,000 results

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, parse-platform

Im using Parse REST API + AngularJS and Im trying to be able to get more than 1000 items per query. I try to develop a recursive function and concatenate each query until I get all the data. My problem is that I am not able to concatenate the JSON objects successfully. Here is what I have:

```
    $scope.getAllItems = function(queryLimit, querySkip, query) {
        $http({method : 'GET',
            url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/myClass', 
            headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'XXX','X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'YYY'},
            params: {limit:queryLimit, skip:querySkip},

        }).success(function(data, status) {
                query.concat(data.results); 
                if(query.lenth == queryLimit) {
                    querySkip += queryLimit;
                    queryLimit += 100;
                    $scope.getAllItems(queryLimit, querySkip, query);
                } else {
                    $scope.clients = query;
                }

            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                alert("Error");
            });
    };
    var myQuery = angular.toJson([]); //Am I creating an empty JSON Obj?
    $scope.getAllItems(100,0, myQuery);
```

Is there any better solution to achieve this?

Comment: Each server response is a complete JSON string or incomplete json string, that must be downloaded in multiple queries?

Comment: If each server response is json-encoded array of some objects, then you can create empty array and for each successfull request add downloaded items to this array.

Comment: My understanding is that is a complete JSON string, Parse API wont let you get more than 1000 item per query, so basically I will get the first 1000 items as a result.

Comment: Ok then. Just create array and add items on each request ;-)

Comment: You're seeding myQuery with a string - I think you just want var myQuery = [];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my recursive function and now its working. Here it is:

```
$scope.getAllItems = function(queryLimit, querySkip, query, first) {

        $http({method : 'GET',
            url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/myClass', 
            headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'XXX','X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'YYY'},
            params: {limit:queryLimit, skip:querySkip},

        }).success(function(data, status) {
                if(first) {
                    query = data.results;
                    first = !first;
                    if(query.length == queryLimit) {
                        querySkip += queryLimit;
                        $scope.getAllItems(queryLimit, querySkip, query, first);
                    } else {
                        $scope.clients = query;
                    }
                } else {
                    var newQ = data.results;
                    for (var i = 0 ; i < newQ.length ; i++) {
                      query.push(newQ[i]);
                    }
                    if(query.length == queryLimit + querySkip) {
                        querySkip += queryLimit;
                        $scope.getAllItems(queryLimit, querySkip, query, first);
                    } else {
                        $scope.clients = query;
                    }
                }
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                alert("Error");
            });
    };
```

Simply pushed each element to my empty array, also I was mutating `queryLimit` instead of `querySkip` in order to iterate through all the elements.

Comment: hi. may i know if angularjs is able to parse more than 1000 records with no problem?

Answer (score 1):

There may be better, more concise ideas available, but this is what I worked out for myself.

In my service ...

```
fetch : function(page, perpage) {
    var query = // build the query
    // the whole answer to your question might be this line:
    query.limit(perpage).skip(page*perpage);
    return query.find();
},

fetchCount : function() {
    var query = // build the same query as above
    return query.count();
},
```

In the controller...

```
$scope.page = 0;       // the page we're on
$scope.perpage = 30;   // objects per page

MyService.fetchCount().then(function(count) {
    var pagesCount = Math.ceil(count / $scope.perpage);
    $scope.pages = [];
    // pages is just an array of ints to give the view page number buttons
    for (var i=0; i<pagesCount; i++) { $scope.pages.push(i); }
    fetch();
});

function fetch() {
    return MyService.fetch($scope.page, $scope.perpage)).then(function(results) {
        $scope.results = results;
    });
}

// functions to do page navigation
$scope.nextPage = function() {
    $scope.page += 1;
    fetch();
};

$scope.prevPage = function() {
    $scope.page -= 1;
    fetch();
};

$scope.selectedPage = function(p) {
    $scope.page = p;
    fetch();
};
```

Then paging buttons and results in my view (bootstrap.css)...

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li ng-click="prevPage()" ng-class="(page==0)? 'disabled' : ''"><a>«</a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="p in pages" ng-click="selectedPage(p)" ng-class="(page==$index)? 'active' : ''"><a>{{p+1}}</a></li>
    <li ng-click="nextPage()" ng-class="(page>=pages.length-1)? 'disabled' : ''"><a>»</a></li>
</ul>

<ul><li ng-repeat="result in results"> ... </li></ul>
```